# SwiftUI PreviewDevice does not set userInterfaceIdiom — how to set userInterfaceIdiom for previews?

Tags: swiftui

I have a view builder that runs a different view depending on the userInterfaceIdiom. I'd like to see the changes reflected on the previews, but simply setting preview device does not work. Is there a way to make this work?

Code is something like this:

```swift
struct HomeView: View {
   @ViewBuilder
   var body: some View {
        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone{
            PhoneHomeView()
        } else {
            PadHomeView()
        }
    }
}
```

The following does not produce the expected result, previews are always in phone view.

```swift
struct HomeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static let deviceNames: [String] = [
        "iPhone X",
        "iPad Pro (9.7-inch)"
    ]

    static var previews: some View {
        ForEach(deviceNames, id: \.self) { deviceName in
            HomeView()
              .previewDevice(PreviewDevice(rawValue: deviceName))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just copy-pasted - works fine with Xcode 11.4

Comment: hmm, interesting.. doesn't work for me on Xcode 11.4.1

Comment: works fine in the iPad simulator but not in the preview